# Sudo apt upgrade не видит доступное обновление

Tags: ubuntu

Захожу в VS code и показывает что доступно обновление, хочу обновить через консоль, пишу

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Но показывает что доступных обновлений нет
Тогда решил написать

```
sudo apt install code
```

Но выходит что установлена последняя версия, но на официальном сайте видно, что в ноябре вышла новая, что делать?

Comment: А VSCode поставлен из репозитория? Тогда ждать когда обновится репозиторий.

Comment: apt update не забыли сделать? Не путайте с upgrade, это разные операции

Comment: @AlexeyTen вроде как .deb файл устанавливал, уже не помню, а можно это как-то узнать?

Comment: @andreymal не забыл, и autoclean и autoremove и dist-upgrade и full-upgrade, а вообще не особо понимаю для чего нужен update, хотя читал про это, пару раз в неделю ввожу команду эту и кэш чищу

Comment: Ну значит скорее всего в используемый вами репозиторий просто не загрузили новую версию

Comment: А что показывает `apt-cache policy code`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen показывает что установлена версия 1.73.1 и кандидат версия 1.73.1

Comment: в мелкософте пока ещё не научились выкладывать в репозиторий)

Comment: Ну тогда ждать.